# Is it possible to have a database of sources on this website?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Being that I'm relatively new to the stack-exchange community I was wondering what additional features could be placed on this site by the moderators.

Is it possible for users to have access to a source database located within the site (like Bar-Ilan, Otzar HaChochma or even Sefaria) and/or even be able to construct a source sheets? I feel like it would help alot with being able to answer and ask questions if that is possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1758 may be of interest to you.

Comment: Note moderators are not developers. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/166155 about moderators. Developers are the people who design, build and maintain the SE engine.

Answer (score 4):

This is a question-and-answer Web site and should focus on that. If you want source sheets, that's what Sefaria is for.